# Django Admin Site: TemplateDoesNotExist?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm trying to get the Django admin interface to display objects from my database, but whenever I click the name of a model, I come across an error:

#### TemplateDoesNotExist at `/myAppName/myModelName/`

I don't understand: Why do I need any templates for the admin interface in the first place?
I thought the admin interface was already pre-made for us, and that we didn't need any custom HTML for it... right?

---

`settings.py`:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',

  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
  'django.contrib.admin',
  # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
  'django.contrib.admindocs',

  'my_app_name',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  '<project_path>/templates',
  '<django_path>/v1_2/contrib/admin/templates',
)
```

`admin.py`:

```
from my_app.models import MyModel
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #my fields here
```

Comment: How do your model and admin definitions look?

Comment: @DontCare4Free: They look like the above.

Comment: is there any message for the exception? Are you by any chance using custom fields? Also, the admin templates shouldn't be in your TEMPLATE_DIRS, since they are automatically included by the admin app.

Comment: Presumably admin uses template loaders to load templates, did you change them in your settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, this is so **tricky**! I just ran into the solution by pure chance:

The problem was that I was going into the admin interface with a URL of the form:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

while in fact I should have said:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

that solved the issue. (!)

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your URLconf